# R shiny app DataTable filter on row names

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

Using the library DT I'm drawing a DataTable in a shiny app. I enabled the filtering with `datatable(df, filter="top")`. Unfortunately, the filter does not apply to row names.

I know that I can add a new column like `df$names<-row.names(df)` but this changes the data and all the subsequent code as to be revised.

I tried to make a copy of the data like `df_copy<-data.frame(df)` but in that case shiny complained because can't access reactive value outside of reactive consumer.

How can I enable a filter on row.names?

Comment: Add the row names as a column.  Take the pain of modifying your existing code.  Filtering *requires* data in df columns.  Row names are an attribute of the object.

Comment: Besides, adding a column should **not** change any code. Data is best seen as an unordered *set* of lists of same lengths. That is, ideally code does not depend on the column order. Only for displaying purposes it make sense to shape the data into a special order, but this happens at rendering time. Other code should treat data w/o assuming a certain column order.

Comment: I have operations on rows in the code, if I add a column they are no longer valid. How can I just add the column for visualization purposes, copying the data and leaving the original one unchanged? I.e. how can I avoid the problem related to "can't access reactive value outside of reactive consumer".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dat <- iris

js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "    var $th = $(this.api().table().header()).find('tr:eq(1)').find('td:first');",
  "    var column = this.api().column(0);",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $th.empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    data.each(function(d, j){",
  "      select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "    });",
  "    select.select2({width: '100px', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "}")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, #container=sketch, 
      filter = "top",
      options = list(
        orderCellsTop = TRUE,
        initComplete = JS(js),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```